# How to remove null datarow from datatable except Autoincrement column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with one autoincrement column. And I want to remove the row which contain null or white space values in all columns except autoincrement column.

```
var dr = TempRowToSelectionDT.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is System.DBNull || string.Compare((field as string).Trim(), string.Empty) == 0)).ToArray();
```

TempRowToSelectionDT is my datatable. I cannot remove the null rows in that datatable. Because I cannot filter column in itemarray and autoincrement column always has values. So I want to remove the rows in that datatable which contains null values in all cells except autoincrement column

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Dim dtSociete As New DataTable
dtSociete.Columns.Add("EmpID")
dtSociete.Columns.Add("EmpFName")
dtSociete.Columns.Add("EmpLName")
dtSociete.Rows.Add("1", "Faraz", "Ahmed")
dtSociete.Rows.Add("2", "Saad", "Aslam")
dtSociete.Rows.Add("3", "", "")
dtSociete.Rows.Add("4", "", "")
dtSociete = dtSociete.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("EmpName") <> "" And r.Field(Of String)("Descrip") <> "").CopyToDataTable()
```